# Create a custom table in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gridbaglayout

I would like to create a table looking like this but with the titles in-sync with the table:

[image]

Any tips on how make the columns being aligned with the rows and also allow auto resize in x-axis? For this I used `GridBagLayout`. Also tried with `JTable` but had problems to customize it to hide all default `JTable` components(like in my picture).

```
public class MyTableExample extends JFrame {

    public MyTableExample(){
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        contentPanel.add(getTitles(),c);
        c.gridy = 2;
        contentPanel.add(getRow(),c);
        c.gridy = 3;
        contentPanel.add(getRow(),c);

        // MainPanel: Helps positioning the contentPanel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(20,20,20,20);
        mainPanel.add(contentPanel,c);

        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getRow(){
        JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        rowPanel.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel col1 = new JLabel("#rowItem");
        JComboBox<String> col2 = new JComboBox<String>();
        JButton col3 = new JButton("rowItem");
        JLabel col4 = new JLabel("rowItem");
        rowPanel.add(col1,c);
        rowPanel.add(col2,c);
        rowPanel.add(col3,c);
        rowPanel.add(col4,c);

        return rowPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getTitles(){
        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        titlePanel.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel t1 = new JLabel("T1");
        JLabel t2 = new JLabel("Title2");
        JLabel t3 = new JLabel("Title33333333");
        JLabel t4 = new JLabel("T4");
        titlePanel.add(t1,c);
        titlePanel.add(t2,c);
        titlePanel.add(t3,c);
        titlePanel.add(t4,c);

        return titlePanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyTableExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: try [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with all the cells being the same size, `GridLayout` would be an easy solution. I'm behind the times on what new layouts are available which might be helpful, but GridBag can have a bit of a learning curve to it. If you want everything to line up, you need to have one GridBagLayout, not one per row.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single panel and place all your components directly in this panel, using a GridBagLayout. That way, all the components will be placed in a single grid, and will thus be aligned correctly.